# Installing Caffe (deep learning) issues

Tags: macos, caffe

I have been able to install Caffe but I had a lot of issues and that's because I didn't follow the instructions very well.

I have a Mac OSx and I'm reading the OSx guide for installation.

In this point:

[image]

when I type `hdf5 opencv` I get:

> "hdf5: command not found"

I've tried to install `hdf5` by `Homebrew` and `MacPorts` but I'm still getting:

> "hdf5: command not found"

Does anyone have any clue?

Thank you very much.

---

according to the answer of @mattias, my binaries in `/usr/local/hdf5` are:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hdf5` is not a command or anything else. The documentation is just bad, it has to be:

`brew tap homebrew/science hdf5 opencv`

---

So, what I mean is, we have to install `hdf5` and then link it to Caffe. But executing hdf5 is not what the guide meant.

Answer (score 1):

You can install hdf5 from source. I just tested on OS X 10.9.5.

```
wget http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/hdf5-1.8.14.tar
```

Unpack,

```
tar zxfv hdf5-1.8.14.tar
```

Enter directory

```
cd hdf5-1.8.14
```

And then,

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/hdf5  # or where you want it
make
sudo make install
```

Then you have it installed in /usr/local/hdf5.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help @mattias , but still "-bash: hdf5: command not found". It was installed in /usr/local/hdf5 but there's no binary called hdf5 to execute